# Why video is not visible in HTML

Tags: html, video

```html
<div id="small_cont1">
  <video controls>
    <source src="\Frontend\compileonline.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <!-- <source src="\Frontend\compileonline.mp4" type="video/ogg"> -->
    Your browser does not support HTML video.
  </video>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine - the control bar appears, the video gets downloaded but the video is not visible.

Comment: What is this path `\Frontend\compileonline.mp4`? Is it API call?

Comment: ***the video gets downloaded*** How do you know that video is downloaded? From where is it downloaded?

Comment: give height and width to video or check the video path